# Sticky table column in an overflow container

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

I Have this table that is basically in a scrollable window since it is pretty big. I have the header sticky and I managed to have one th sticky, although it has the same class as the td. The td stays sticky only if I remove the overflow from tbody. Is there any way to have them both?

```
table {
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    height: 485px;
}
td, th {
    min-width: 150px;
}
.check{
    min-width:20px;
}
.stick-column{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background: #ffff !important;
    z-index:9;
}

      <div class="fixed-scrollbar">
        <table id="film-tbl" class="table table-striped" style="font-size: 70%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="stick-column check"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="stick-column check"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>               
              <tr>
                <td  class="stick-column check">
                </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

And I have a javascript function that is supposed to automatically make any column sticky

Comment: Please also share the markup that corresponds with this CSS, thanks!

Comment: Just did, hope that should be enough. It;s nothing fancy